# Entity Framework using Repository Pattern, Unit of Work and Unity

Tags: entity-framework, inversion-of-control, unity-container, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Using a combination provided from [this example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and [this implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11785/ef-code-first-with-repository-unitofwork-and-dbcontextfactory) I am trying to create a solution that decouples the `UnitOfWork` class from the individual repositories, as they violate the Open-Closed Principle, since every time you added a new repository you would have to modify the `UnitOfWork` class.  I am using Unity as the IoC container to wire up dependencies.

The problem I have is that in automatically wiring up the `UnitOfWork`, `IDbContext` and the repositories (`IEmployeeRepository` and `ICustomerRepository`) using Unity, the repositories will be injected with separate instances of the `UnitOfWork`, which, of course, defeats the purpose.  I need to share the context across the repositories, and it seems I am missing a piece to this puzzle - at the moment (see Service layer) the `UnitOfWork` instantiated will be different to the `UnitOfWork` for each of repositories.

How do inject the `IUnitOfWork` into the service layer and pass this instantiated *shared* `UnitOfWork` class to the respective repositories, using Unity and dependency injection?

Here's my proposed (fabricated) solution:

**Repositories**

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    TEntity Create();
    // omitted for brevity
}

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{       
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public Repository(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _context = uow.Context;
    }

    public virtual TEntity Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);         
    }   

    // omitted for brevity      
}

public interface IEmployeeRepository : IRepository<Employee>
{
}

public interface ICustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer>
{
}

public class EmployeeRepository : Repository<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeRepository(IUnitOfWork uow)
        : base(uow)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomerRepository : Repository<Customer>
{
    public CustomerRepository(IUnitOfWork uow)
        : base(uow)
    {
    }
}
```

**DbContext Factory**

```
public interface IDbContextFactory
{
    DbContext GetContext();
}

public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public DbContextFactory()
    {
        _context = new MyDbContext("ConnectionStringName");
    }

    public DbContext GetContext()
    {
        return _context;
    }
}
```

**Unit Of Work**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void SaveChanges();
    DbContext Context { get; }
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private bool disposed = false;

    public UnitOfWork(IDbContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        _context = contextFactory.GetContext();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        if (_context != null)
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public DbContext Context
    {
        get { return _context; }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public class CompanyService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;
    private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;

    public CompanyService(IUnitOfWork uow, IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository, ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {           
        _uow = uow;
        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    // over-simplified example method
    public void AddEmployeeAndCustomer()
    {
        _employeeRepository.Create(new Employee {Id = 1, Name = "Test Employee"});
        _customerRepository.Create(new Customer { Id = 2, Name = "Test Customer" });

        _uow.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a per request lifetime manager so that you only get one UnitOfWork instance and one DbContext instance for the duration of a request.  Unity 3 has the [Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/) which has a [PerRequestLifetimeManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec38) which lets you do this.

If you are not using ASP.NET then you could probably use a PerResolveLifetimeManager.  Another approach I've seen is a HierarchicalLifetimeManager combined with a child container (which makes the registrations a singleton within the child container).

Comment: Thanks, sounds exactly what I need.  And fortunately I'm already using Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC - I just didn't know it had the lifetime manager baked right in. So, essentially I wouldn't even need to pass in the IUnitOfWork into the service layer, just the repositories since they expect the UOW (which would've already been instantiated) to be passed into their respective constructor?

Comment: Interestingly, the [Per Request Lifetime Management article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec38) suggests a better approach may be to store/retrieve the shared items, which require their state to be stored across requests, in the `System.Web.HttpContext.Items` collection.

Comment: Ignore my first comment, I would still need to pass in the UOW into the service as the service is reliant on `_uow.SaveChanges()`